# Problem with setting integral limits for flux

Tags: integration, area

I have a function $$y=\frac{x^3}{2H^3+1}$$ I am calculating flux through an area defined by this function. So I have

$$\text{flux} = \int_0^{2H}y\,\mathrm dx$$

This is what I cannot understand - if for the same problem, I define the flux boundary as $(-H,\, H)$, flux will become

$$\text{flux} = \int_{-H}^{H}y\,\mathrm dx$$

In principle, both scenarios should result in the same result but they don't. I cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

I will appreciate any insights.

Thanks, 
John.

Comment: I think you should check whether function is odd or even before reaching to any conclusion.

Comment: can you pls elaborate? How can one decide whether to use (-H, H) or (0, 2H) as the limits?

Answer (score 0):

Note, Your function is odd :: $f(-x)=-f(x)$    (assuming H is constant)
Thus $$\int ^H _{-H}f(x)=\int^H_0f(x) + \int^0 _{-H}f(x)$$
$$\int ^H _{-H}f(x)=\int^H_0f(x) + \int^H _{0}f(-x)$$
$$\int ^H _{-H}f(x)=\int^H_0f(x) - \int^H _{0}f(x)$$
$$\int ^H _{-H}f(x)=0$$.

See the picture? Thus the two are not equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(x)=sin(\frac{1}{2}x)$ 
${\displaystyle\int_{0}^\pi \sin\frac{1}{2}x\ dx+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} sin\frac{1}{2}x\ dx  =2 + 2 = 4}$ 
Now consider the integral from $-\pi$ to $\pi$. It should make sense that 
${\displaystyle\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin\frac{1}{2}x\ dx=0}$. 
 The integral ${\displaystyle\int_{-A}^{A} f(x)\ dx={\displaystyle\int_{0}^{2A} f(x)\ dx}}$ 
is only true when $f(x)={|\ f(x)\ |}$ on the interval $(-A,2A)$. In other words, you can only equate the two integrals as such when the function is positive on the interval. In terms of area this means that you have both a positive area and negative area. The result will be a *net* area, rather than the total area which is what you are trying to find.
 With your function, consider the interval where $y$ is positive and negative.